# Magnific Popup - Disable arrows on first/last items

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I'm using magnific-popup and I am wondering if there is a way to disable the arrows on the first/last item in a gallery.

I have read through the documentation, but cannot find anything about this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to modify any source files, you can just override prev/next functions:

```
callbacks: {
    open: function() {
        var mfp = $.magnificPopup.instance;
        var proto = $.magnificPopup.proto;

        // extend function that moves to next item
        mfp.next = function() {

            // if index is not last, call parent method
            if(mfp.index < mfp.items.length - 1) {
                proto.next.call(mfp);
            } else {
               // otherwise do whatever you want, e.g. hide "next" arrow
            }
        };

        // same with prev method
        mfp.prev = function() {
            if(mfp.index > 0) {
                proto.prev.call(mfp);
            }
        };

    }
}
```

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#how_to_override_some_function_without_modifying_the_source_files

Comment: Thanks; that is indeed the proper way to do it. Sorry I ended up hacking around your code and props for the plugin, it's **awesome**!!

Answer (score 6):

For anyone still looking, here is the nearly best (I hope so!) solution to the discussed topic:

It follows the authors preferred way and does not require modification of the plugin's source-code.

You can read more about how to extend or override class functions in the plugin documentation: [magnific-popup/documentation.html#faq](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#faq)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    // add this code after popup JS file is included
    $.magnificPopup.instance.next = function() {    
        // if index is not last, call parent method
        if($.magnificPopup.instance.index < $.magnificPopup.instance.items.length - 1) {
            // You may call parent ("original") method like so:
            $.magnificPopup.proto.next.call(this /*, optional arguments */);
        }
    };
    $.magnificPopup.instance.prev = function() {
        // if index is not first, call parent method
        if($.magnificPopup.instance.index > 0) {
            // You may call parent ("original") method like so:
            $.magnificPopup.proto.prev.call(this /*, optional arguments */);
        }
    };

    $.magnificPopup.instance.toggleArrows = function() {
        // if index is not last, show the Next-Image Arrow Button:
        if($.magnificPopup.instance.index < $.magnificPopup.instance.items.length - 1) {
            $(".mfp-arrow-right").show();
        }
        // if index is last, hide the Next-Image Arrow Button:
        if($.magnificPopup.instance.index == $.magnificPopup.instance.items.length - 1) {
            $(".mfp-arrow-right").hide();
        }

        // if index is not first, show the Previous-Image Arrow Button:
        if($.magnificPopup.instance.index > 0) {
            $(".mfp-arrow-left").show();
        }
        // if index is first, hide the Previous-Image Arrow Button:
        if($.magnificPopup.instance.index == 0) {
            $(".mfp-arrow-left").hide();
        }
    };

    $.magnificPopup.instance.updateItemHTML = function() {
        $.magnificPopup.instance.toggleArrows();
        // You may call parent ("original") method like so:
        $.magnificPopup.proto.updateItemHTML.call(this /*, optional arguments */);
    };

    /* - image gallery - */
    $(".zoom-gallery").each(function() {  
        $(this).magnificPopup({
            delegate: 'a', // the selector for gallery item
            type: 'image',
            callbacks: {
              open: function() {
                // Will fire when this exact popup is opened
                // this - is Magnific Popup object

                this.toggleArrows.call(this);
              }
            },
            gallery: {
                enabled:true
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Any reason you're `$(".zoom-gallery").each(function() { $(this).magnificPopup({ ... }); });` instead of just  `$(".zoom-gallery").magnificPopup({ ... });`?

Comment: @henry yes the .each(... is an iteration over each instance. In the iteration-body with `$(this).mag...` I ensure that I run the magnificPopup Plugin for the current object in scope of the iteration-body. I think this way I was ensure that I can have multiple instance of the plugin running and iterate over them.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I modded it. Sure not the best but the worst way but it's working for me.

Hope it helps

EDIT: Code surrounded by /*lmdrk*/ comments it's what I've added

In jquery.magnificpopup.js

arround line 29

```
/**
 * Private vars
 */
var mfp, // As we have only one instance of MagnificPopup object, we define it locally to not to use 'this'
    /*lmdrk*/
        is_first_item = false,
        is_last_item = false,
    /*lmdrk*/
    MagnificPopup = function(){},
    _isJQ = !!(window.jQuery),
```

arround line 165

```
open: function(data) {

        var i;
        /*lmdrk*/
            is_first_item = false;
            is_last_item = false;
        /*lmdrk*/
        if(data.isObj === false) {
```

arround line 1465

```
        _document.on('keydown'+ns, function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 37) {
              if (mfp.currItem.index != 0)                                    /* lmdrk */
                mfp.prev();
            } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
                if (mfp.currItem.index != mfp.items.length-1)                   /* lmdrk */
                  mfp.next();
            }
```

arround line 1474

```
_mfpOn('UpdateStatus'+ns, function(e, data) {
                if(data.text) {
                    data.text = _replaceCurrTotal(data.text, mfp.currItem.index, mfp.items.length);
                }
                /*lmdrk*/
                if (mfp.currItem.index == 0)
                        is_first_item = true;
                    else if (mfp.currItem.index == mfp.items.length-1)
                        is_last_item = true;
                /*lmdrk*/
            });

            _mfpOn(MARKUP_PARSE_EVENT+ns, function(e, element, values, item) {
```

arround line 1493

```
_mfpOn('BuildControls' + ns, function() {
                if(mfp.items.length > 1 && gSt.arrows && !mfp.arrowLeft) {
                    var markup = gSt.arrowMarkup,
                        arrowLeft = mfp.arrowLeft = $( markup.replace('%title%', gSt.tPrev).replace('%dir%', 'left') ).addClass(PREVENT_CLOSE_CLASS),
                        arrowRight = mfp.arrowRight = $( markup.replace('%title%', gSt.tNext).replace('%dir%', 'right') ).addClass(PREVENT_CLOSE_CLASS);
          /*lmdrk*/
          if(is_first_item)
            arrowLeft.css('display', 'none');
          if(is_last_item)
            arrowRight.css('display', 'none');
          /*lmdrk*/
                    var eName = supportsFastClick ? 'mfpFastClick' : 'click';
```

and arround line 1543

```
next: function() {
            mfp.direction = true;
            mfp.index = _getLoopedId(mfp.index + 1);
            /*lmdrk*/
            if (mfp.arrowLeft.css('display') == 'none')
        mfp.arrowLeft.css('display', 'block');
            if (mfp.index == mfp.items.length - 1)
              mfp.arrowRight.css('display', 'none');
            /*lmdrk*/
            mfp.updateItemHTML();
        },
        prev: function() {
            mfp.direction = false;
            mfp.index = _getLoopedId(mfp.index - 1);
            /*lmdrk*/
            if (mfp.arrowRight.css('display') == 'none')
              mfp.arrowRight.css('display', 'block');
            if (mfp.index == 0)
              mfp.arrowLeft.css('display', 'none');
            /*lmdrk*/
            mfp.updateItemHTML();
```

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look at that as soon as I get home. I can see how you've got it to work there, so I'm confident. The only thing I don't understand is what the mipalo1 and mipalo2 variables are doing? You seem to set them and update them, but never actually use them.

Comment: I have accepted your answer: It does indeed do what I need. There are only a couple of issues: I'm still not sure what the mipalo variables are doing, will wait for a reply on that. Also, if the user opens the gallery on the first or last item, the arrows will still show until they either go forward or backward.

Comment: @Jazzer Modified mipalo1 and mipalo2 var names to more explanatory variable names: **mipalo1 = is_first_item** and 
**mipalo2 = is_last_item** now

Comment: @Jazzer you were right, I forgot to mark code arround line 1493 (added to answer) which deals with the problem you noticed and uses the variables, because you can't access to mfp inside that snippet of code

Comment: Aha. That makes more sense. Although seeing my addition below, I think you do have access to mfp at that point. At least what I did worked for me (I don't know if we have different versions, your line numbers don't quite match up with mine)

Answer (score 0):

Further to @Daniel Garcia's answer, I used the following to make sure that the arrows do not appear the first time the gallery is shown when it starts on the first or last item

around line 1383

```
                    // Polyfill for :before and :after (adds elements with classes mfp-a and mfp-b)
                if(mfp.isIE7) {
                    _getEl('b', arrowLeft[0], false, true);
                    _getEl('a', arrowLeft[0], false, true);
                    _getEl('b', arrowRight[0], false, true);
                    _getEl('a', arrowRight[0], false, true);
                }

                mfp.container.append(arrowLeft.add(arrowRight));
                /* ----- Start of my editing ----- */
                if (mfp.index == 0)
                    mfp.arrowLeft.hide();
                if (mfp.index == mfp.items.length - 1)
                    mfp.arrowRight.hide();
                /* ----- End of my editing ----- */
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
callbacks: {
    change: function() {
        var mfp = $.magnificPopup.instance;
        var container = $(mfp.container);

        if (mfp.index >= mfp.items.length - 1) container.addClass('mfp-last');
        else container.removeClass('mfp-last');
        if (mfp.index == 0) container.addClass('mfp-first');
        else container.removeClass('mfp-first');
    }
}
```

plus this css

```
.mfp-first .mfp-arrow-left {
    display: none;
}

.mfp-last .mfp-arrow-right {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents to complete and simplify the answer of Dmitry Semenov, which was a good hint finding the way to hide those arrows for a noob like me. I removed the "next" and "prev" functions overridings which are not needed IMO: the arrows must be hidden on display, not on prev/next click.

```
callbacks: {
    open: function() {
        var mfp = $.magnificPopup.instance;

        // if index is last, hide "next" arrow
        if(mfp.index == mfp.items.length - 1) {
        mfp.arrowRight.css('display', 'none');
        }

        // same with "prev" arrow and first item
        if(mfp.index == 0) {
        mfp.arrowLeft.css('display', 'none');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 callbacks: {
            open: function() {
                    var mfp = $.magnificPopup.instance;
                    var proto = $.magnificPopup.proto;

                // Initial arrows show/hide check
                if( mfp.index < 1)   
                    $(".mfp-arrow-left").hide();
                if( mfp.index >= mfp.items.length - 1) 
                     $(".mfp-arrow-right").hide();

                // NEXT Method
                    mfp.next = function() {
                    // if index is not last, call parent method
                        if( mfp.index < mfp.items.length - 1) {
                            proto.next.call(mfp);

                        // arrows show/hide check
                            $(".mfp-arrow-left").show();
                            if( mfp.index >= mfp.items.length - 1) 
                                 $(".mfp-arrow-right").hide();

                        } else {
                           // otherwise do whatever you want, e.g. hide "next" arrow
                            $.magnificPopup.close(); 

                        }
                    };

                // PREV Method
                    mfp.prev = function() {
                        if(mfp.index > 0) {
                            proto.prev.call(mfp);

                        // arrows show/hide check   
                        $(".mfp-arrow-right").show();
                        if( mfp.index < 1)   
                            $(".mfp-arrow-left").hide();
                        }
                    };

                } // open function
            } // callbacks
```

Comment: would you mind giving some explanation beside the code?